# Epson V370 Scanner - One-Button Scanning Possible?

Tags: scanner

I have an Epson V370 scanner, which claims to offer "one-button scanning". However, all the buttons on the scanner actually just open a scanning application on the PC.

I want to be able to press a button on the scanner and have it automatically scan the file and save as a PDF to disk.

Is this actually possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CharlieRB is partly correct.

A additional software is required in order for it to be completely automatic.

However the software you are looking for is called **Epson Event Manager**. It basicly lets you assign a action to each button on your scanner. In your case to automaticly save it as a PDF file on a assigned destination on your computer or network, without having to go through Epson scan, or opening any additional dialogs.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  This sounds closer to what I'm looking for.  I no longer have the scanner, so haven't checked it though.

Comment: @Stefan – after some struggling with [buttons not working](https://superuser.com/q/1543400/287473) on this scanner with Windows 10, I found a solution. Also your answer helped to complete that puzzle.

Answer (score 2):

The `Scan to PDF` button  ([image]) has to be set up first in order to use the feature. Each person's expectation of how *"automatic"* things will be is different. So, consider there may be some user interaction required for the scanner and its software to know what you want.

[According to the manual](http://files.support.epson.com/htmldocs/prv37_/prv37_ug/projs_2.htm#S-00900-00800), you must set up the `Scan to PDF` feature.

[image]

It appears once you have it set up, you can use the `PDF` button to scan directly.

[image]

These images are for reference and not meant to instruct you how to set up your scanner. Please refer to the manual.

Comment: Thanks for the link; unfortunately this is basically the same as the built-in help documentation, and doesn't address what I need.  Specifically, I do not want to have to deal with ANY dialogs after pressing the scan pdf button.  I want it to immediately scan and save the document.

Comment: I believe it will do that once you set it up and save the settings. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. I haven't seen any indication that there might be a way to prevent the dialog appearing in the first place. Have you tried this and found a different result, or are you inferring it from your reading of the manual?

Comment: As my answer states, "according to the manual" is how I answered. I do not have this exact equipment, but I have experience with many different brands and models. What I was pointing out is the manual leads one to believe it would work the way you'd like once it was set up. It is unfortunate if it does not do exactly as you want (refer to the second sentence of my answer).