# Some buttons on scanner Epson V37/V370 do not work with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, scanner

Unlike in Windows 7, in Windows 10 after installation of Epson drivers, buttons on the scanner work in limited way:

```
Button       Supposed function            Actual effect                     As expected?
------------ ---------------------------- --------------------------------- ------------
 A           Scan to e-mail               Does nothing                          No
 B           Scan to PDF                  Opens Scan to PDF window              Yes
 C           Scan to printer              Opens standard Epson Scan tool        No
 D           Scan using Epson Scan        Opens standard Epson Scan tool        Yes
```

[image]

How to make buttons **<kbd>A</kbd>** and **<kbd>C</kbd>** work as expected again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 10, not all four scanner buttons are directly received by basic Epson driver. However, after some research, this can be fixed by proper arrangement of installed components and settings.  This is the final scheme:

[image]

Enablement steps (corresponding to the above numbers):

1. You probably already have Epson Scan driver installed from [V37 Support](https://epson.com/Support/Scanners/Perfection-Series/Epson-Perfection-V37/s/SPT_B11B207201) page or [V370 Support](https://epson.com/Support/Scanners/Perfection-Series/Epson-Perfection-V370/s/SPT_B11B207221) page. If not, download and install 
   **Scanner Driver and EPSON Scan Utility v3.9.2.5** (or higher).
2. From the same location, download and install **Epson Copy Utility v4.1.1** (or higher). It is located in **Utilities** section.
3. From the same location, download and install **Epson Event Manager v3.11.53** (or higher). It is located in **Utilities** section.
4. In Windows 10, go to **Settings** > **Devices** > **Printers & Scanners** > click your scanner in the list and make sure the device is powered on and connected > **Manage** button > **Scanner Properties** link (visible only if the scanner is online) > **Properties** button > Allow changes to device: **Yes** > **Events** tab > for each of 4 scanner events in dropdown menu, set the action to **Start this program: Epson Event Manager**

Notes:

- now you should see 4 icons in your Start menu: **EPSON Scan** • **EPSON Scan Settings** • **Copy Utility** • **Event Manager**
- some scanner buttons need to pressed longer (about 1 second) to activate their tool
- **Important: the tool is sometimes displayed behind all open application windows** what may create an impression that nothing happened after pressing the button. Action: Minimize other windows one-by-one until you can see the window with expected Epson tool.
- button **Scan to E-mail** starts standard **Epson Scan** tool and only after scanning it shows **Attach to E-mail** tool
- when confirming settings in **Attach to E-mail** tool, Microsoft Outlook must be already running, otherwise the tool fails to start it properly and the tool cannot be used anymore until the computer is restarted (this is probably a bug)
- if the regular connection with the scanner broke (it is no longer responding), start the application **EPSON Scan Settings**, it can usually fix it